# Prolog Syntax Issue - Variable Functor

Tags: prolog

I've been trying to use this code for a while now and it says there is a syntax error but I'm not sure what it is.

```
studies(ahmed,history(77,63)).
studies(john,chemistry(0,21)).

passed(Person,Subj):-
    studies(Person, Subj(Work, Exam)),
    Final is Work + Exam,
    Final >=60.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a variable for the name of a clause, you could write instead:

```
passed(Person,Subj):-
    (Subj=history-> studies(Person, history(Work, Exam))
    ;Subj=chemistry-> studies(Person, chemistry(Work, Exam)),
    Final is Work + Exam,
    Final >=60.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly "parameterize" the functor, but you can use the `=../2` operator, which unifies a functor and arguments with a list:

```
passed(Person, Subj):-
    studies(Person, SubjWorkExam),
    SubjWorkExam =.. [Subj, Work, Exam],
    Work + Exam >= 60.
```

This avoids hard-coding the various subjects in your predicate. Also, the comparison operator `>=/2` will evaluate expressions, so the separate `is/2` is not required.